# Is $n! = o(n^n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Intuitively, it seems that $n! = o(n^n)$. We can associate each value in the factorial with a single $n$ to divide by, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$ seems to be $0$.

However, I think I have encountered a contradiction. It turns out that $\log(n!) = \Theta(n\log{n})$ (which we can show with Stirling's approximation) or $\log(n!) = \Theta(\log{n^n})$. The log function is strictly increasing, so we can just remove them, so that means that $n! = \Theta(n^n)$, which goes against my earlier hunch of $n! = o(n^n)$.

I must be missing something, right?

Comment: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}=0$ does indeed [hold](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143813/how-to-approach-convergence-n-nn-to-infinity).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$${n!\over n^n}={1\cdot 2\cdots n\over n\cdot n\cdots n}\leq {1\over n}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Just because the log function is strictly increasing doesn't mean it preserves asymptotics! For a simple example of this, note that $\log(3^n)=\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}\log(2^n)$, and so $\log(3^n)$ is $\Theta(2^n)$. However, $3^n$ is clearly not $\Theta(2^n)$.

Essentially, if $\log f(n)$ is $\Theta(\log(g(n))$, that means $f(n)/g(n)$ is exponential or smaller.

Comment: Thanks! Why is $\log(3^n)=\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}\log(2^n)$ true?

Comment: By basic properties of logs: $\log(3^n)=n\log(3)$, and $\log(2^n)=n\log(2)$. (Alternately—and equivalently—you could think of it as a version of the [change-of-base formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base).)

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$$u_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$$
then 
$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^{-n}\to e^{-1}<1$$
so by ratio test the series $\sum u_n$ is convergent so $u_n\to0$ and the desired result follows.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Stirling's approximation states that
$$ n! \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$$

so $\frac{n!}{n^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty0]{} 0$. Your problem is that *you cannot take the exponential of equivalents*. For instance, take $f(n)=n$, $g(n)=n+\sqrt(n)$. Clearly, $f(n)\sim g(n)$, yet
$$ e^{g(n)} = e^{n+\sqrt{n}} = e^{f(n)}e^{\sqrt n} = \omega\left(e^{f(n)}\right)$$

Comment: If you can read French (or make abstraction of the French words around the statements), see [this page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op%C3%A9rations_sur_les_%C3%A9quivalents#Composition) for what operations you can/cannot do on equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the log of Stirling's formula, you get
$$\log(n!) \approx n\log n - n + \tfrac{1}{2}\log n + \tfrac{1}{2}\log 2\pi$$
You are keeping only the leading term, $n\log n$, in your question. If you take the difference of the logs (to get handle on the ratio of the original quantities), you get
$$\log(n!)-\log(n^n)\approx -n + \text{ lower order terms}$$
Note that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, this does indeed tend to $-\infty$. So the original ratio tends to 0.