# Compute the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponentiation, factorial

I am trying to calculate the following limit without Stirling's relation. 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n!}{n^n}
\end{equation}
I tried every trick I know but nothing works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that $n! \leq n^{n-1}$.

Comment: It would converge to $0$ as for a very large $n$, $n!$ is puny compared to $n^n$

Comment: Hint:$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{n}{n}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n}\cdot\frac{n-3}{n}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{3}{n}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$From here you can "see" that one is certainly _losing_ as $n\to\infty$...

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/whats-the-limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnnn

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904113/limit-cn-n-nn-as-n-goes-to-infinity

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By estimating all the factors in $n!$ except the first one, we get:
$$0 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{n-1}}{n^n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n} $$ of positive terms. The ratio of two consecutive terms is $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)!/(n+1)^{n+1}}{n!/n^n}= \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n=\left[ \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right]^{-1} $$ which tends to $e^{-1}<1$. It follows from the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) that the series converges, and by the necessary condition for convergence of series the limit is obtained. We have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}=0. $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

We have that $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot n<n\cdot n \cdot ...\cdot n$ ,$n-1$ times.

Comment: You probably want to have $n-1$ times in there not $n$ because that doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: Haha,correct,wrote it wrong.thnx