# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

Prove that

> $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n} = 0$

I've already considered using l'Hoptials rules but I cannot take the derivative of a factorial (as it is a discrete function).

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579825/compute-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-fracnnn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to get an explicit upper bound for the fraction:

$0 < \dfrac{n!}{n^n} = \dfrac{1\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot n}{n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n} < \dfrac{1}{n}$, and $\dfrac{1}{n} \to 0$. So the answer follows by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Write it as $\dfrac{n}{n}\dfrac{n-1}{n}\dfrac{n-2}{n}\cdots\dfrac{2}{n}\dfrac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\frac{3!}{3^3} = \frac{6}{27} = \frac{2}{9} < \frac{3}{9} = \frac{1}{3}$. A naïve conjecture from this observation might be that $\frac{n!}{n^n} < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \ge 3$. This is in fact true, as can be proved by a straightforward induction.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach: [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) tells you $n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$. That tells you the thing you're taking the limit of is approximately $\frac{2 \pi n}{ e^n}$. This goes to 0 as $n \to \infty$.

Alternatively, you can use the bound from Stirling's approximation is $n! \leq e \sqrt{n} n^n e^{-n}$. Then, $0 \leq \frac{n!}{n^n} \leq e \sqrt{n} e^{-n} \to 0$.

Comment: You don't need this much power to do this problem...

Comment: Also, you are using approximations in a proof. These aren't very convincing in this context when there is a straightforward way to prove it.

Comment: Of course, but that answer had been posted a bunch of times (hence "another approach"). And its generally a useful thing to know, along with squeezing something to determine a limit.

Answer (score -1):

By using Gosper's approximation, or Stirling's approximation, $n!$ is approximately
\begin{align}
n! \approx n^{n} \ e^{-n} \ \sqrt{ \left( 2n + \frac{1}{3} \right) \pi }
\end{align}
which then leads to
\begin{align}
\frac{n!}{n^{n}} \approx \ e^{-n} \ \sqrt{ \left( 2n + \frac{1}{3} \right) \pi }.
\end{align} 
Now taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ yields
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \frac{n!}{n^{n}} = 0.
\end{align}