# Prove $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

Prove $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$.  I have tried this several ways.  I tried using the ratio test, I tried to expand it... I'm not really sure where to go.

When I expand, I get $$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3).....}{nnnnnn......}$$ I don't know if trying to expand this is helpful, but I'm just not sure where to go with this problem... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Stirling approximation?

Comment: $\frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{1}{n}\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{n} \le \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: overkill?${}{}{}$

Comment: kinda irritating when teachers ask us to prove something that is so obviously true that just looking at it should be proof enough haha.

Comment: @stackreader Often, the purpose of proving an "obvious" statement is to practice using some important technique (approximating with upper bounds, in this case).

Comment: See [Compute the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/579825) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/579825).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea. Note that
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\cdots\frac{1}{n}$$
Every term in this product is at most $1$ so we have that
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\cdots\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Awesome! I like it.

Comment: Just an added bit of clarity: We are replacing every factor (except for the last one!) with its upper bound of $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a combinatorial proof. The numerator is the number of bijections from $[n]\to[n]$; the denominator is the number of functions from $[n]\to [n]$.  For each bijection $\sigma$, we can define $n$ different functions $\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n$ s.t. $\tau_i|_{[n-1]}=\sigma$ and $\tau_i(n)=i$. So the expression in the limit is $\leq 1/n$.

Comment: (+1) Nice combinatorial interpretation. Just rephrasing: we want to estimate the probability that a random function $f:A\to A$, with $|A|=n$, is injective. Things may "go wrong" in so many ways that the limit probability is clearly zero.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test works:

$$\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^{n}}}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^n}{n!}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{e}<1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log(k)\le \int_1^{n} \log(x)\,dx$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(n-1)!&=e^{\log((n-1)!)}\\\\
&=e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log(k)}\\\\
&\le e^{\int_1^{n} \log(x)\,dx}\\\\
&=n^ne^{-(n+1)}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we see that

$$0\le \frac{n!}{n^n}\le ne^{-(n+1)}$$

whereupon application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$$

And we are done!